# How to fix "std::invalid_argument" in std::stoi

Tags: c++, c++11, c-strings

I'm trying to do a socket server, but when I tried to pass numbers I got `std::invalid_argument` and I don't know why. I remade the code to make it more simple and here it is:

```
std::string a = std::to_string(32);
char texto[5];
strcat(texto,a.c_str());
printf("%s", texto);//Isn't printing a string that you can convert to a number
std::string b = texto;
int s = std::stoi(texto);
std::cout << s;
```

I expect the output of 32, but I'm getting the error.

Comment: Before calling strcat all bytes in texto should be set to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char texto[5];
strcat(texto,a.c_str());
```

`texto` is not initialised, so it contains garbage values. `strcat` will have to start by reading them looking for the NUL terminator, giving you Undefined Behaviour.

You were probably looking for `strcpy` instead of `strcat`.

Comment: Even better, avoid using old C functions that are much more prone to issues like this.